# Jenkins pipeline trigger pipeline on Agent

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have A Jenkins Server and 3 Agents. Builder, Programmer, and Tester. The three agents are pretty self explanatory. The Builder builds a Yocto image and saves the output files. The Programmer takes the saved image files and places them onto a device under test. The Tester then runs a suite of automated tests against the new image files.

If my Builder's Yocto stage is complete I would like it to kick off a pipeline on the Programmer agent. I am having a hard time finding an example of this. I assume it would be something similar to this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'YoctoBuildNode'
    }
    
    stage('Yocto') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (isStagingOrMaster()) {
                        echo "Performing a full Yocto build for Staging!"
                        sh "chown -R $USER:$USER ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                        sh "chmod -R a+rwx ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                        sh "${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkins_quick_start.sh"
                    } else {
                            echo "Building the main Application for branch ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                            buildProject()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    stage('Doxygen') {
    
    }
    state('Trigger Programmer') {
        agent {
            label 'ProgramNode'
        }
        Not sure what to do here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#common-options), specifically second example in this section.

In short, you declare top-level `agent none`, and then declare appropriate `agent` on every step of your build.

Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Yocto') {
            agent { label 'YoctoBuildNode' } 
            steps {
                echo 'Yo, I'm cool Yocto'
                println agentName
            }
        }
        stage('Example Test') {
            agent { label 'ProgramNode' } 
            steps {
                echo 'Ehh, I'm boring JDK'
                println agentName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different agent for each stage. each stage will be executed on own agent, and to pass artifacts from one agent to another need to use [stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) [unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed)
because agents don't share filesystem

```
pipeline {
  agent none 
  stages {
    stage('Yocto') {
      agent { label 'YoctoBuildNode' } 
      steps {
        script {
          if (isStagingOrMaster()) {
            echo "Performing a full Yocto build for Staging!"
            sh "chown -R $USER:$USER ${env.WORKSPACE}"
            sh "chmod -R a+rwx ${env.WORKSPACE}"
            sh "${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkins_quick_start.sh"
          } else {
            echo "Building the main Application for branch ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            buildProject()
            stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Example Test') {
        agent { label 'ProgramNode' } 
        steps {
          unstash 'builtSources'
          println agentName
        }
    }
  }
}
```